# Jquery .click() doesn't fire for <a> tag

Tags: jquery, click

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":button").click(function () {
        $(this).next('a').click();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div style="text-align:center">
            <input type="button" value="More" class="button">
            <a style="display:none" href="/Resource/PhysicianMaterials">aaa</a>
        </div>
```

In this code `.click()` doesn't fire for  tag, can anyone say what is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `click` event *is* firing, however, a `click` *does not go to the URL* when you're talking about an anchor (that happens at the browser/native event level, it's not JavaScript triggered).

Instead you need to do that navigation yourself, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":button").click(function () {
        window.location = $(this).next('a').attr('href');
    });
});
```